# Read all Emails In a Domain For Office365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I want to read all emails in my domain against a query using Office365 Outlook API. Currently, I am enumerating one user at a time and extracting all the emails for it

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{userId}/messages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/%7BuserId%7D/messages)

This approach is not scalable as in the case of 1000+ users it will take a lot of time. I want to extract the emails for all users against a query but without enumerating individual users.

Comment: You could do that with Graph Data Connect https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-datasets otherwise look at compliance/ediscovery https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/content-search?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: I agree with @GlenScales. Don't use the regular Graph API calls to read, rather use the Microsoft Graph Data connect when you try to consume bulk info.